# How to enable Adobe Camera Raw in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, digital, haze

The `Adobe Camera Raw` filter is greyed out, how do I enable it?

I am using `Adobe Photoshop CC 2015`. I have a JPG file that I opened up in the Photoshop editor. In the layers panel I right clicked the layer and selected `Convert to Smart Object`. I then tried to go to:

```
Filter > Camera Raw Filter
```

..but this option is greyed out. Not sure why? Might it be that the image mode is incorrect? It is currently set to:

```
CMYK Color | 8 bits per channel
```

I hope someone can help me with my confusion.

Comment: You opened a JPEG, or is that a typo? If not, Camera Raw are for raw files, not JPEG. Raw is the format that your camera (assuming it can shoot raw files) stores images when set to RAW in the camera body's settings. You cannot apply a Raw filter to a JPEG file.

Comment: @Gmck Camera Raw, despite the name, can operate on JPEGs.

Comment: @Gmck I bought myself `Teach yourself Photoshop` so I am working through the samples in the book. Yes they used a JPG for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camera Raw filter only works with 8/16-bit RGB images. Even if you're intending to print the image, I suggest you do your edits in RGB, then convert to CMYK in the final stages of editing. CMYK has a smaller colour space than RGB, so you'll have more colours out of gamut and shadows can be rather blocky.

Switch the image to RGB with

```
Image > Mode > RGB Color
```

you'll see the bit-depth lower down in the menu. If it's a jpg, switching it to 16-bit won't do anything useful as the information has already been lost in the 8-bit save.

Hope that

Comment: I bought myself `Teach yourself Photoshop` so I am working through the samples in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the photo as PNG. Then open again so that in the file that you need it in then you may now use camera raw filter

Comment: Why would saving as PNG help?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe camera raw is not a file type Adobe camera raw is no different than lightroom.  Yes it is a raw processing application however the file does not have to be a raw file in order to use adobe camera raw.  I actually have my mac to open camera raw for any image file whether it be a raw or not.  But as one person said camera raw filters are only for files with an rgb colour space not cmyk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).